# is there a way to save Data on another page in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm building a simple tool that will allow users to save contact information on another page and redirect back to the index page. I try many things and I still can't figure it out, thanks in advance.

code below

url.py

```
 url(r'^lead/$', views.lead, name='lead'),
```

view.py

```
def lead(request):
    new_item=Blogger.email
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/app')
```

index.html

```
<a href="/app/lead" title="add lead"   >Add lead</a>
```

models.py

```
class Blogger(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField()
```

Comment: What's wrong with creating a model for it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?